# How to perfectly forward `auto&&` in a generic lambda?

Tags: c++, c++11, auto, lambda, perfect-forwarding

C++14 supports generic lambdas. However, the following code is rejected by clang 3.4.

```
#include <utility>

void f(int);
void f(int&);

int main()
{
    [](auto&& v) { f(std::forward<auto>(v)); }(8); // error
}
```

How to perfectly forward `auto&&` in a generic lambda?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

`auto` is not a type so I’m not surprised this doesn’t work. But can’t you use `decltype`?

```
[](auto&& v) { f(std::forward<decltype(v)>(v)); }(8);
```

[Scott Meyers has more details.](http://scottmeyers.blogspot.com.tr/2013/05/c14-lambdas-and-perfect-forwarding.html)

Comment: DRY -- `#define FORWARD(x) std::forward<decltype(x)>(x)` -- ick.

Comment: @Yakk But also AGUOM: Avoid Gratuitous Use Of Macros. ;-)

Comment: If something requires a macro to DRY, figure out how to improve the language!

Comment: Without rehashing a general discussion about macros, is there anything broken about this particular macro? It won't work with parameter packs (`auto ...`) but otherwise it is correct isn't it?

Comment: @Aaron The name is wrong: every long-lived macro should be namespaced to avoid name clashes (i.e. be called something like `MY_LIBRARY_NAME_FORWARD`), which of course greatly decreases its readability. More fundamentally, the macro simply isn’t necessary. I agree with Yakk about “DRY” but the thing being repeated here is a single, simple identifier rather than a complex expression.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid are you sure it doesn't work with parameter packs, as `[](auto&&... obj){do_something(FORWARD(obj)...);}`?

Comment: I'm not sure, @bit2shift. I'm not entirely sure why I wrote that :) .  In hindsight, the macro should work fine with expansion. It's likely that I simply didn't understand pack expansion very well when I wrote that first

Comment: @KonradRudolph Don’t you also in general want to `std::decay` the `decltype` here, that is `std::forward<std::decay_t<decltype(v)>>(v)` ?