# Forwarding arguments with auto in C++20?

Tags: c++, c++20

In C++20, is the following function not ill-formed:

```
void f(auto&&... args) { /*...*/ }
```

and, if not ill-formed, is there a way to forward arguments in the body (without modifying the signature) in exactly the same fashion as the following function:

```
template<typename... Args>
void f(Args&&... args) {
    g(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

If so, what should replace the use of `Args` as the template argument to `std::forward`?

Comment: I kinda feel like this is already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24535430/how-to-perfectly-forward-auto-in-a-generic-lambda

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica This being variadic makes it sufficiently different I think. The correct syntax is arguably non-obvious.

Comment: @cigien - That's minutia... and a maybe grasping at straws. The grammatical difference that a pack incurs compared to a single argument is a couple of  additional ellipsis.

Comment: Yeah, I'm fine either way with it being a duplicate.  I suspected `decltype` was the right answer, but it wasn't clear to me that it handled all the reference-collapsing / forwarding reference stuff correctly.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Sure, but the grammatical difference is not what a lot of future visitors would care about. and the spelling could reasonably be `<decltype(args...)>`. Compilers don't say much more than "parse error here". I'm on the fence about the dupe from that pov.

Comment: @cigien - *"could reasonably be"*, except it's not. And also not the focus. The issue here is lack of an explicit template parameter to feed into `forward`, and that is exactly the same issue the other question addresses.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Ok, I see that point. It's not really the focus of the question. I still think it's reasonable for someone to expect the syntax to be `decltype(args...)` or something like that, but I'm fine with the closure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with the help of `decltype`.

```
void f(auto&&... args) {
    g(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
}
```

When being passed lvalues, `decltype(args)` yields type `T&`, `std::forward` would forward them as lvalues. When being passed rvalues, `decltype(args)` yields type `T&&`, `std::forward` would forward them as rvalues. Note that it's a little different with the template version, in which `T` is specified as template argument for `std::forward`; the effect (i.e. forwarding as rvalues) is the same for both cases.

Comment: FWIW, that's exactly the same syntax we can use in variadic generic lambdas since C++14.